# Flex datagrid: how to populate datagrid from a web service response data?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a function that retrieve a json response from a webservice:

```
            private function suggest(evt:Event):void
            {

                var f:GoogleSuggest = new GoogleSuggest(keyword.text);
                keywords = new ArrayCollection(f.keywords);
                keywords.refresh();
                dg.dataProvider = keywords;

            }
```

And this is my datagrid:

```
    <s:DataGrid id="dg" x="228" y="132" width="500" >
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="keyword" headerText="Keyword"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
```

However my datagrid will not get populate, but if I click the header like sorting column, the data are there.

So the question is: how can I populate my datagrid once the service gives me the response?

Answer (score 0):

I'd call `invalidateDisplayList()` or `validateNow()` methods on the Datagrid to get this to work.